# Container group support for Windows

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-multi-container-group

Below is a quote from the above URL.

Is there a technical reason that windows is not supported? 
Or will it eventually be supported?  If yes, any idea when windows will be supported?

Multi-container groups are currently restricted to Linux containers. While we are working to bring all features to Windows containers, you can find current platform differences in Quotas and region availability for Azure Container Instances.

Comment: totally offtopic for SO, docs clearly say: not supported.

Comment: "Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers."  This has an answer.  It is not opinion based.  I didn't ask "Which is better, linux or windows containers?".  The statement from Microsoft is ambiguous as to whether the feature is delayed or not possible.  So this question has a "real" answer.

Comment: its not. it clearly says: currently limited to linux containers.

Comment: Multi-container group is currently restricted to Linux containers because network namespace is not available on Windows. Maybe it would be supported for windows in future.

Comment: Thank you Charles.  If you add it as a answer, I will mark it.  "network namespace".

Comment: I have added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-container group is currently restricted to Linux containers because network namespace is not available on Windows. Maybe it would be supported for windows in future.

You can get more details following this [link](https://xpirit.com/2017/11/12/containers-as-a-service-in-azure/).

Comment: Thanks Charlies.  I'm copying the relevant quote from the article here: "Containers are always part of a container group. Even if you deploy a single container, it will be placed into a new group automatically. When using Windows containers, a group can have only one container, this is because network namespaces are not available on Windows."

Comment: I'm glad the answer is helpful to you! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Product team from ACI here - docs are correct that Windows containers do not support multi-container groups yet. We will update the documentation to be clearer about that.

We do plan to support multi-container groups for Windows though, currently estimated for support in late 2018 / early 2019. Stay tuned to [Azure updates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/) for the latest.

Comment: Hi @jluk - I'd like to create a sidecar to provide HTTPS support to a Windows-based container, but it seems this isn't possible currently. Are there any timelines for implementation? Many thanks.